# Antonym of a musical or creative "influence"

Tags: antonyms

If I were composing music or some other creative media, you might say that my work is "influenced" by this or that person, or that this or that person is an "influence".  If I wanted to express that my work is also in direct opposition to another artists' work or style, is there a word that describes this?  A sort of "anti-influence", if you will.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An *influence* is something that produces an effect, so if your work is in opposition to a particular artist or style, you are still influenced by it. Perhaps you mean to ask for the opposite of a musical or creative *inspiration*.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the helpful feedback.  Let me clarify that I was looking for a noun.  I apologize for not specifying this!  However, I feel that the answers and comments provided have given me what I need.  *Negative influence* comes the closest to what I was looking for.  Gnawme's suggestion of using antithetical was also very helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An adjective expressing direct opposition is *[antipodal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antipodal)*, "On opposite sides of the globe; diametrically opposite".  Example: "The work of these artists is antipodal."  This does not suggest that one artist influenced the other, merely that the natures of their works are in direct contrast.

Note, influence can be positive *or* negative; work done in direct opposition to another's work still has been *influenced*, or *negatively influenced*, not *anti-influenced*.  If you want to say that one person's work has had no influence on another's, then call their work *independent*.

Answer (score 2):

Per Merriam-Webster:

> **antithetical**, *adj*. : marked by direct opposition : exactly opposite

"His spare, elegant orchestrations were *antithetical* to his rival's bombastic, overly commercial works."

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "be in [direct] contrast to":

> The sound color of her music is **in contrast to** her teacher's, but her sense of musical structure is similar to his.

You may also use **alternative**.

Comment: I assume you mean "The sound color of her music is in contrast to that of her teacher's" rather than "The sound color of her music is in contrast to her teacher".